# Translation of "He has been allowed to dance, but I haven't."

Tags: translation, english-to-german

There are two versions that are possible:

1)

> Er hat tanzen dürfen, aber ich habe nicht **gedurft**.

2)

> Er hat tanzen dürfen, aber ich habe nicht **dürfen**.

Which one is correct?

(Updated: 'haben' declension corrected.)

Comment: Er hat tanzen gedurft -- ich aber nicht (?)

Comment: @Em1: In all other cases I stick with what Karl Valentin said: *Mögen hätt ich schon wollen, aber dürfen hab ich mich nicht getraut*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apart from the incorrect form of *haben,* example 1) is correct:

> Er hat tanzen dürfen, aber ich habe nicht gedurft.

This is because *dürfen* is a full verb in the second part of the sentence (in contrast to a modal verb as in the first part of the sentence, where there is an infinitive form (tanzen) attached to it) and therefore is inflected differently. You could also *dürfen* as a modal verb in the second part:

> Er hat tanzen dürfen, aber ich habe nicht tanzen dürfen.

However, as c.p. already mentioned, repeating in detail what is negated is uncommon, and a simple *ich nicht* suffices:

> Er hat tanzen dürfen, ich nicht.

Furthermore, using the perfect and not the imperfect for *dürfen* seems odd to me, however I cannot pinpoint why. So, I cannot think of a context in which I would not write or say:

> Er durfte tanzen, ich nicht.

Comment: The last sentence is the most natural IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

The use of of perfect and imperfect strongly depends on the context in which they are used. In colloquial German, both tenses are considered identical by the majority of the speakers, whereas in written texts the imperfect is used much more often - and rightfully so.

In spoken German "Ich habe gestern getanzt" (perfect) and "Ich tanzte gestern" (imperfect) are considered identical, even though only the latter version is grammatically correct, since the German perfect is 'officially' used in the same way the English present perfect is.

Answer (score 2):

Ich würde übersetzen:

> Ihm wurde erlaubt zu tanzen - mir nicht.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say in this situation (apart from that I *hate* dancing ;) )

```
Er durfte schon tanzen, ich nicht.
```

Comment: Wieso kommst Du auf "schon"?

Comment: Das "schon" betont eben, dass *er* tanzen darf, aber ich eben nicht. Ich würde es eben so sagen und nicht anders.

Comment: Achso, ich verstehe. Ich habe das _schon_ zeitlich verstanden (Er durfte schon tanzen; ich musste mir erst passende Schuhe besorgen), aber ein _schon_ kann auch wie von Dir gezeigt benutzt werden, es wird dann betont - darauf bin ich so nicht gekommen.